# How to use neo4j spatial index with PHP

Tags: php, neo4j, lucene, neo4j-spatial, neoxygen

I am using Neo4j 2.3.2 with ZF2 and Neoxygen/NeoClient. I have latitude and longitude of users stored in my db. I want to display user and map on page like in airbnb. Users are displayed on left side and map will be displayed on right side and markers will be shows on map according to lat, long of users. This part I have done but I want to filter my result as someone moves over map. Like if I zoom-in on map and move to some location then it should only show me the result of that area. I have heard of Spatial index but I don't know how to use it. I have some doubts regarding spatial index:

- Can we use spatial index with Neo4j 2.3.2 ?
- Can we use spatial index with PHP ?
- Can we create spatial index of data which is already stored in db ?
- Is it possible to create spatial index automatically like neo4j_auto_index which I use for lucene fulltext search query ?